# Cómo generar Script SQL desde el mapeo de entidades java

Tags: java, oracle, jsf, jpa, netbeans-8.2

Tengo mi proyecto en NetBeans con Maven, jpa 2.2, JSF y Oracle, pero por cuestiones técnicas debí formatear el equipo y la copia de base de datos quedó mal, mi pregunta es 
¿Cómo puedo generar nuevamente el script de la base de datos teniendo el mapeo de las entidades?

Comment: Si estás usando hybernate podes crear el esquema de base de datos a partir de los mapeos con `property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create"`. Con este valor la base se recrea con cada ejecución asi que una vez creada cambiale el valor a update, validate, o a none.

Comment: @Juan, esto debería ser una respuesta, no comentario. Y Jhon debería decir si le sirve etc. Cosa, que, por otra parte, nadie hace, por desgracia.

Comment: @juan, gracias por tu respuesta, estoy usando eclipserlink, no estoy usando hibernate, hay alguna forma de hacerlo con eclipserlink? O cómo podría implementar la línea que me das ya que no he usado hibernate y no sé cómo usarla. Gracias de antemano por su atención.

Comment: @Evgeni Enchev, gracias por tu respuesta, tienes razón en que no había comentado, pero respondiendo tu pregunta, no creo que me sirva la solución de juan y si me sirve no se como implementarla, ya que no he usado nunca hibernate, agradezco si me puedes dar una ayuda con eclipserlink o cómo podría cambiar a hibernate y usar la solución de juan. Gracias por su colaboración.